# NSUndoManager with AppKit in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have a Xamarin application written in C#/Xamarin.Mac and runs on iOS/Mac.
It has a list, a sublist, and each sublist item contains set of documents
(kinda like folders, subfolders, files).

Each "document" is a complex beast, and when I display it, I have an NSView/UIView
that contains a whole lot of sub-NSViews and layers (thousands of lines, many rich
text boxes (a subclass of NSTextView/UITextView), background images, attachments etc etc). A large scrolling visual feast :-).

Obviously I want a shared NSUndoManager object across the lot - meaning you
can type into a text box, draw a line, type into a different text box,
drag-drop and attachment etc,
then undo those steps and the "right thing" will happen in the reverse order
across the many subviews. Plus I also need that UndoManager to be the one used
by the Window for managing the Edit|Undo menu (so undo items show up).

In the documentation by apple, it says you have two choices:

- use the NSResponder approach, where you can request an undoManager from the NSResponder, which walks up the chain and if no-one else has an undo manager, will
  return an undo manager provided by the NSWindowDelegate function **windowWillReturnUndoManager**. If there isn't one, the NSWindow creates one.
- an NSDocument based approach, where the NSDocument will provide the undoManager, which probably comes from the same method as above.

The documentation from Xamarin is pretty hopeless on this.
However it does show that undoManager is missing from [NSResponder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/appkit.nsresponder?view=xamarin-mac-sdk-14) whereas it is not missing from the [AppKit documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsresponder).

What I have done (that sort of works) is to add an undo manager to my top level view (that holds the thousands of subview/layer objects) and passed it to the subviews, so that they use it for all "undoManager.RegisterUndo". This works on iOS and most macs, but not all. On many macs, for some reason, the window doesn't seem to use the Undo Manager in my view, and therefore the Edit|Undo menu is always empty.

What I probably *should* be doing is either:

1. switch to an NSDocument, NSDocumentController architecture (that would be an enormous job and not something I want to contemplate yet).
2. find a way to get the NSUndoManager directly from the window delegate.

I have tried 2 by adding the following to a class:

```
        NSUndoManager theUndoManager = null;
        [Export("windowWillReturnUndoManager:")]
        public NSUndoManager WindowWillReturnUndoManager(NSWindow window)
        {
            if (theUndoManager == null)
                theUndoManager = new NSUndoManager();
            return theUndoManager;
        }
```

and then setting that class as the window's delegate. In *theory* the guard
isn't required because the docs say that this function will only be called once.

This doesn't work.

Does anyone have some insights they can provide or some sample code showing how this should be done (NOTE: needs to be for mac and *not* using NSDocument).

Many thanks.

Comment: What is the difference between those 'working mac' and not working macs?

Comment: That is an excellent question, and I haven't found anything significant. Working: MacBook Pro (intel, but recent), latest updates, and is my dev machine. Not working: MacMini (intel but recent), latest updates, is the QA machine. I'm just going to confirm a another macbook...

My current thinking is that it is a timing issue, or perhaps the lack of dev tools on the QA machine causes problems.